# ElasticSearch query with diacritics / accents in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, encoding, diacritics

I have the following expression: "noapte bună" and I'm trying to get the same result when I'm searching for "bună" or "buna".

I have followed to tutorial here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html but to no result.

This is my code:

```
$params = ['index' => 'asciiv3', 'body' => [
    "settings" => [
        "analysis" => [
            "analyzer" => [
                "folding" => [
                    "tokenizer" => "standard",
                    "filter" =>  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "mappings" => [
        "asciiv3" => [
            "properties" => [
                "saying" => [
                    "type" =>           "string",
                    "analyzer" =>       "standard",
                    "fields" => [
                        "folded" => [
                            "type" =>       "string",
                            "analyzer" =>   "folding"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]];
self::$instance->indices()->create($params);
```

and this is the query array:

```
'multi_match' =>
    array(
        "type" =>     "most_fields",
        "query" =>    "bună",
        "fields" => [ "saying", "saying.folded" ]
    )
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. This is my setup:

```
PUT asciiv3
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "asciiv3": {
      "properties": {
        "saying": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "fields": {
            "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST /asciiv3/asciiv3/1
{
  "saying":"bună ziua"
}
POST /asciiv3/asciiv3/2
{
  "saying":"buna ziua"
}

GET /asciiv3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type": "most_fields",
      "query": "bună",
      "fields": [
        "saying",
        "saying.folded"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With these results:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.2712221,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "asciiv3",
            "_type": "asciiv3",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2712221,
            "_source": {
               "saying": "bună ziua"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "asciiv3",
            "_type": "asciiv3",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.028130025,
            "_source": {
               "saying": "buna ziua"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```